# SQL/SpatiaLite: How to insert a default value into certain columns when inserting data from another table?

Tags: sql, default, sql-insert, spatialite

I have a new table, with these columns (all NOT NULL):

```
creation_date, created_by, attribute_1, attribute_2, geometry
```

I also have an old table:

```
attribute_1, attribute_2, geometry
```

I want to insert the data from the old table through INSERT INTO / SELECT / FROM. However this obviously gives me an error for the creation_date and created_by columns because the old table does not have any. How do I insert a default value for these colmuns while inserting the rows from the old table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply choose some literals. Unless that data exists elsewhere and you can look it up with a join, I would suggest something like:

```
INSERT INTO newtable
SELECT date('now') as creation_date, 
'Legacy Data' as created_by, attribute_1, attribute_2, geometry
FROM oldtable
```

Answer (score 1):

While creating the new table set the two new attributes as default attributes

CREATE TABLE NEWTABLE 
(COLUMN1 int default(X) NOT NULL,
 COLUMN2 int default(Y) NOTNULL,
COLUMN3 int, COLUMN4 int)
Here X and Y are values that will be provided to the columns if any INSERT happens, they can be updated afterwards. For COLUMN3 and 4 data can be inserted from any other table